# How to count all objects in a queryset related to a specific fields value?

Tags: python, django

I have a Model `Poller` that has a field `category`. I have a filtered queryset of `Poller`. Now I would like to count the objects for each category like so:

```
Poller 1: poller_category - Sport
Poller 2: poller_category - Sport
Poller 3: poller_category - Tech
Poller 4: poller_category - Tech
Poller 5: poller_category - Fashion
```

should return a dictionary somewhat to `counts = {'Sport' : '2', 'Tech' : '2', 'Fashion' : '1'}`

```
# Model

class Poller(models.Model):

    poller_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    poller_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Category(models.Model):
    """
    Model to define categories and their color styles
    """
    poller_category = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    category_color = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
```

```
# View / query

    qs = Poller.objects.filter(
        created_by__username=username).order_by(
        '-poller_category')
```

Not sure but the ordering itself might be obsolet probably.

Comment: You `Category` has a `name` field or something similar?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ah apologize, missed the Category model. Added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify for each `name` `Category`, the `Count` of the number of items:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Category.objects.annotate(
     numpollers=Count('poller', filter=Q(poller__created_by__username=username))
)
```

Here the `Category` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.numpollers` with the number of `Poller` objects where the `created_by__username` is set to the *`username`*.

Comment: Ah so this solution approaches the rabbit from the other side so to say. Nice!